# I keep seeing the grub menu after deleting the partition with linux

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

On my pc i had a dual boot with Ubuntu 20 and Linux Mint 20.
I decided to delete the Linux Mint 20 partition, but when I start the pc the grub menu still appears and in the options it still appears, besides Ubuntu, also linux mint 20. I checked the disk and I have a partition for the file system and one with ubuntu.
Why am I still seeing the grub menu?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I edit my Grub bootloader entries (Hide, Rename, Remove)? Preferably doing it manually, and not with a program](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81660/how-can-i-edit-my-grub-bootloader-entries-hide-rename-remove-preferably-doi) = `sudo update-grub` is probably your best option

Comment: FYI GRUB is the bootloader for Ubuntu even if it's the only operating system installed.  The reason you're seeing it displayed is probably because you didn't remove the Linux Mint GRUB entry.  Also, please note that you've identified an Ubuntu version that does not exist.  Desktop and sever versions of Ubuntu are identified by the *yy.mm* format.  You are likely referring to Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Have you run `sudo update-grub`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove fedora from boot menu after formatting the disk of fedora?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1254285/how-to-remove-fedora-from-boot-menu-after-formatting-the-disk-of-fedora)

Answer (score 0):

`sudo update-grub` solves the issue!